# how to get duplicate sub string count in db2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

How to get duplicate sub string count in db2 sql

```
    col 1       
    |abc_123|  
    | abc_2 |   
    |xyz_123|
```

output will be

```
        col1         output         
        |abc_123|       |2|    
        |abc_23 |       |1|
        |xyz_123|
```

How to get count using `substr()`, `locate()` command and `group by` clause in SQL db2 ,I want two col i.e col1 and output

Comment: What do *you* mean by "duplicate sub string count"?  It is not obvious to me.

Comment: in column 1 duplicate substring is there ex abc_ i want count of substring before '_'

Comment: Do you mean  count of abc is 2

Comment: right ! i want count 2 for abc @Rams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take the part of the string and then do the group by on that part to find the count of those part of string

```
select substr(col1, 1,locate('_',col1)-1) col1, count(col1)  from table t1
group by substr(col1, 1,locate('_',col1)-1)
```